# Finding user's current location with Parse and saving it in the Parse database

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, parse-platform, location

Sorry this is a newbie question. I've followed the Parse documentation on PFGeopoints but I don't think I'm getting it right. Where should I put this line: placeObject["location"] = point

My goal is to: 
1. Find CURRENT ADDRESS of the USER.
2. Show location with a pin on a the map and written on a label. 
3. Transfer the user's address to Parse

Please help!

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:40.0, longitude:-30.0)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just haven't finished writing the code yet. Try to and then ask a question about any actual problem you have.

Comment: I have. I didn't put the other stuff in there, just the map stuff that's in relevance to the question asked. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Show it.nyour question refers to `placeObject` but that isn't shown anywhere

Comment: When I do put     placeObject["location"] = point     it gives me an "expected declaration" error. Any idea why?

Comment: Show where you're defining it and using it